# How to sort LinkedLists using compareTo in java8

Tags: java, linked-list, compareto

I need to sort a linked list of StudentInfo objectsx using compareTo().

This is my StudentInfo clas

```
package mahaffy_lab4;
import java.util.*;
/**
 *
 * @author student
 */

 public class StudentInfo implements Comparable<StudentInfo>
 {

private LinkedList<Object> classes = new LinkedList<>();
private String sid, name;


public StudentInfo(String sid, String name)
{
    this.sid = sid;
    this.name = name;

}

public void AddClass(Object aClass)
{       
   classes.add(aClass);
}
@Override
public int compareTo(StudentInfo studentA)
{

    return this.name.compareTo(student.name);
}
@Override    
public String toString()
{
    return "Name: " + name + "   SID: " + sid;
}
```

}

But this is where my issue is. in my main/test class, nothing i have tried works. this is the last try I made:

```
private LinkedList<Object> students = new LinkedList<>();

public String GetAllStudents()
 {   

     Collections.sort(students, new Comparator<String>() {
         @Override
         public int compare(StudentInfo o1, StudentInfo o2) {
            return Collator.getInstance().compare(o1, o2);
         }            
     });   

     return students.toString();
 }
```

Please, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Which field do you want to sort on?

Comment: I need to sort the students alphabetically by name.

Comment: What is your expected and actual output? Is `students` in your second block a `List<StudentInfo>`?

Comment: Something like `students.sort(Comparator.comparing(StudentInfo::getName));` should do it.

Comment: Oh, I see I left out a part of code. In my main/test class there is a LinkedList called students

Comment: I have to implement the Comparable interface in the StudentInfo class

Comment: That's pretty simple too: `@Override public int compareTo(StudentInfo s) { return this.name.compareTo(s.name); }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the declaration:

```
private LinkedList<Object> students = new LinkedList<>();
```

LinkedList is a list of `Object`, so values of the list are compared as `Object`, not as `StudentInfo`.

To fix the problem, re-declare the list:

```
private LinkedList<StudentInfo> students = new LinkedList<>();
```

Answer (score 1):

This should be your `StudentInfo` class with `Comparable` interface implementation:

```
class StudentInfo implements Comparable<StudentInfo> {

    private final int num;

    @Override
    public int compareTo(StudentInfo studentA) {
        return Integer.compare(num, studentA.num);
    }
}
```

*This is client code:*

```
List<StudentInfo> studentInfos = new LinkedList<>();
Collections.sort(studentInfos);
```

You did not provide detailed infor about compare two `StudentInfo`. In this example `StudentInfo` will be sorted according to their `num`.

**P.S.**
To be more flexible, I recommend you to avoid `implements Comparable<StudentInfo>`. It is much better to provide separate comparators. Moreover, you can add more of them in the future.

`StudentInfo` with additional comparators:

```
class StudentInfo {

    private final int num;
    private final String name;

    public static final Comparator<StudentInfo> SORT_BY_NUM = Comparator.comparingInt(s -> s.num);

    public static final Comparator<StudentInfo> SORT_BY_NAME = (s1, s2) -> {
        int res = s1.name.compareToIgnoreCase(s2.name);
        return res != 0 ? res : SORT_BY_NUM.compare(s1, s2);
    };

}
```

*Client code:*

```
List<StudentInfo> studentInfos = new LinkedList<>();
studentInfos.sort(StudentInfo.SORT_BY_NUM);  // sort by num
studentInfos.sort(StudentInfo.SORT_BY_NAME); // sort by name
studentInfos.sort(StudentInfo.SORT_BY_NAME.reversed()); // sort by name reversed order
```

Comment: The actual problem is in the list declaration, not in the comparator.

Answer (score 0):

The method signature for `Collections.sort()` (at least, the version you're using) is `public static <T> void sort(List<T> list, Comparator<? super T> c)` In other words, the type argument for the comparator must be a parent type of the type argument for the list. You're passing in a `List<StudentInfo>`, but a `Comparator<String>`. After all, you want to compare `StudentInfo` objects and not `String`s.

You have two options here: Have `StudentInfo.compareTo()` compare based on name, like the line you've commented out. Then, in your call to `Collections.sort()`, don't include another `Comparator`.

Or, give `StudentInfo` some kind of `getName()` method, and use something like this instead:

```
Collections.sort(students, new Comparator<StudentInfo>() {
         @Override
         public int compare(StudentInfo o1, StudentInfo o2) {
            return o1.getName().compareTo(o2.getName());
         }            
     });
```

Comment: When you say don't include another comparator, do you mean like this?

     Collections.sort(students, new Comparator<StudentInfo>() {
             @Override
             public int compare(StudentInfo o1, StudentInfo o2) {
                return o1.getName().compareTo(o2.getName());
             }            
         });

Comment: No, just `Collections.sort(students)`. Since `StudentInfo` implements `Comparable`, this will just use `StudentInfo.compareTo()` for comparisons. [Here's the Javadoc.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort\(java.util.List\))